# EasyAdmin, I can't view pictures from a foreign key (only url text)

Tags: image, templates, fixtures, easyadmin

My problem : I have an entity City, and I want to view images (or just one) of each cities.

It's a OneToMany, the images table was made with fixtures (so an url adress)

I have in my code:

a construct

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

a collection

```
    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Image>
     */
    public function getImages(): Collection
    {
        return $this->images;
    }
```

and a __tostring

```
    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
```

I tried

```
            ArrayField::new('images')
                ->onlyOnDetail(),
```

```
        `CollectionField::new('images'),`
```

and
`AssociationField::new('images'),`

Please, can somebody help me ?
I want to view one or many images, not a string or a number